# How to set the width of the TableRow in xml

Tags: android, xml, tablerow

I would like the width of the TableRow to the width of the phone screen.
My codes are :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="fill" 
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/Button01"
                            android:layout_width="48dp"
                            android:layout_height="48dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_search"
                            android:onClick="search" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="48dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="Employer?date?program?"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/taboneviewlist"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>


</TabHost>
```

The result is as following (in the black rectangle):
[image]
The width of the search icon plus the width of the edittext is not equal to the width of the phone.
Why?

### Thank you

I solved this problem using the following codes:

```
                        <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"       
                        android:gravity="fill" 
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/Button01"
                            android:layout_weight="0.1"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_search"
                            android:onClick="search" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                            android:layout_weight="0.9"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:hint="Employer?date?program?"/>
                    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"       
                        android:gravity="fill" 
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/Button01"
                            android:layout_weight="0.1"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_search"
                            android:onClick="search" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                            android:layout_weight="0.9"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:hint="Employer?date?program?"/>
                    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like switching your layout_width to "match_parent" should fix it. It might also have to do with inputType being "textMultiLine".

```
                   <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Employer?date?program?"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried "match_parent", but it did not work.

Comment: Did you get this fixed? I can try helping more today if not

Comment: No. Still stuck in this bug. Thank you